# Zeroes of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that any solution to the equation $y''+xy=0$ has at least 15 zeroes on the interval $[-25,25]$.
Please give me a hint.

Comment: This is Airy differential equation. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: From a Russian problem book (Apasov D., DE problem book)

Comment: I would begin with the following: Suppose $a,b$ are two consecutive zeros. Then $\int_a^b yy'' = -\int_a^b (y')^2$, integration by parts. So, $\int_a^b xy^2 = \int_a^b (y')^2$. Estimate the integral on the left from above using $x\le b$ and Wirtinger's inequality. This will give a bound on $b-a$.

Comment: i think you need to use strum comparison theorem.

Comment: Note that there are no zeroes for negative $x$.